# How to include a parent pointer with a insert function in Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, parent-child, parent

I have a find_successor function and I wanted to call current.parent but I realized that it's a None type because in my insert() I never included parent as a pointer. I was wondering how I could implement a parent pointer into my insert() without having to modify the code too much.

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.parent = None
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.data = data

class Tree(object):
 PREORDER = 1
 INORDER = 2
 POSTORDER = 3

  def __init__(self):
    # Do not create any other private variables.
    # You may create more helper methods as needed.
    self.root = None

  def print(self):
   # Print the data of all nodes in order
   self.__print(self.root)

  def __print(self, curr_node):
    # Recursively print a subtree (in order), rooted at curr_node
    if curr_node is not None:
        self.__print(curr_node.left)
        print(str(curr_node.data), end=' ')  # save space
        self.__print(curr_node.right)

  def insert(self, data):
    # Find the right spot in the tree for the new node
    # Make sure to check if anything is in the tree
    # Hint: if a node n is null, calling n.getData() will cause an error
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = Node(data)
    else:
        current = self.root
        while True:
            if current.data > data:
                if current.left == None:
                    current.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    current = current.left
            elif current.data < data:
                if current.right == None:
                    current.right = Node(data)
                    break
                else:
                    current = current.right
            else:
                break
```

And this is my find_successor function that I'm working on where I can use a helper method to find the node but it doesn't have a parent.

```
    def find_successor(self, data):
# helper method to implement the delete method but may be called on its own
# if the right subtree of the node is nonempty,then the successor is just
# the leftmost node in the right subtree.
# If the right subtree of the node is empty,then go up the tree until a node that is
# the left child of its parent is encountered. The parent of the found node will be the
# successor to the initial node.

# Return object of successor if found else return None
    current = self.__find_node(data)
    if current.right:
       while (current.right):
          current = current.right
          if current.left:
              current = current.left
          else:
              return current
       return current
   else:
      print(current.parent.data)


  def __find_node(self, data):
# returns the node with that particular data value else returns None
   current = self.root
   while current is not None:
       if (data > current.data):

         current = current.right
       elif (data < current.data):
          current = current.left
       elif (data == current.data):
          return current
   return None
```

Here are my test cases

```
class T3_successor(unittest.TestCase)`:

   def test_successor(self):
     print("\n")
     print("successor function")
     tree_success = lab3.Tree()
     tree_success.insert(8)
     tree_success.insert(3)
     tree_success.insert(10)
     tree_success.insert(1)
     tree_success.insert(6)
     tree_success.insert(4)
     tree_success.insert(7)
     tree_success.insert(14)
     tree_success.insert(13) 

     easy_success =tree_success.find_successor(8).data
     medium_success = tree_success.find_successor(10).data
     tough_success = tree_success.find_successor(7).data

     self.assertEqual(easy_success, 10)
     self.assertEqual(medium_success, 13)
     self.assertEqual(tough_success, 8)

print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be complicated: in your `insert()` method when you set the node to your new node also set they parent (you don't it now) to be the last node you came from.
When you will do that each node except the root will have a pointer to their parent as you wanted.

Comment: Do you mind adding some code to elaborate? I tried something similar but everytime I called the parent it was either just pointing at the current data point or pointing towards a nonetype...

Comment: Yes it should look something like this (only showed for one side due to character limitations)

` def insert(self, data):
      if self.root is None:
        self.root = Node(data)
    else:
        current = self.root
        while True:
            if current.data > data:
                if current.left == None:
                    current.left = Node(data)
                   current.left.parent = current`

Comment: Thank you! I realized I had an error on find_successor in that in that the first test case I got was 8 and of course 8 doesnt have a parent so I wouldnt be able to print the parent of that! Wouldn't have spotted that without your input, thanks :))